# Why this script works fine if run as user, but faili if run from rc.local?

Tags: lxc

I have some troubles with lxc unprivileged containers on Debian.
I follow this method:

a)I create the user unprivileged with home in /var/lxcunpriv

```
useradd -m -d /var/lxcunpriv lxcunpriv
```

b)I install the require packages

```
apt -y install lxc libvirt0 libpam-cgroup libpam-cgfs bridge-utils cgroupfs-mount
```

c)I change the file lxc-net
vim /etc/default/lxc-net

```
USE_LXC_BRIDGE="true"
```

d)I restart lxc-net

```
systemctl restart lxc-net
```

e)check, all green(works fine)

```
lxc-checkconfig
```

f)I apply this

```
sh -c 'echo "kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1" > /etc/sysctl.d/80-lxc-userns.conf'
sysctl -w -p --system
```

g)as a NOT root user I did

```
cat /etc/s*id|grep $USER
```

h)It return 100000-165536, so...

```
usermod --add-subuids 100000-165536 lxcunpriv
usermod --add-subgids 100000-165536 lxcunpriv
```

i)I give some permission on /var/lxcunpriv

```
cd /var/lxcunpriv
setfacl -m u:100000:x . .local .local/share
```

l)I configure the usernet, bridge1 is the name of my bridge net

```
echo "lxcunpriv veth bridge1 10"| tee -i /etc/lxc/lxc-usernet
```

m)I create the dirs

```
su - lxcunpriv
mkdir -p .config/lxc
```

n) then..

```
echo \
'lxc.include = /etc/lxc/default.conf
# Subuids and subgids mapping
lxc.id_map = u 0 100000 65536
lxc.id_map = g 0 100000 65536
# "Secure" mounting
lxc.mount.auto = proc:mixed sys:ro cgroup:mixed
lxc.apparmor.profile = unconfined
 
# Network configuration
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.link = bridge1
lxc.network.flags = up
lxc.network.hwaddr = 00:FF:xx:xx:xx:xx'>.config/lxc/default.conf
```

o)I edit /etc/lxc/default.conf

```
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.link = bridge1
```

p)update the .config/lxc/default.conf

```
lxc-update-config -c .config/lxc/default.conf
```

q)I create the first container

```
lxc-create --name mylinux -t download
lxc-start --name mylinux
lxc-attach --name mylinux
```

Now the problem, when I start the container...

```
lxc-start --name mylinux
lxc-start: mylinux: lxccontainer.c: wait_on_daemonized_start: 833 No such file or directory - Failed to receive the container state
lxc-start: mylinux: tools/lxc_start.c: main: 330 The container failed to start
lxc-start: mylinux: tools/lxc_start.c: main: 333 To get more details, run the container in foreground mode
lxc-start: mylinux: tools/lxc_start.c: main: 336 Additional information can be obtained by setting the --logfile and --logpriority options
```

Searching on forum I found this workaround

```
#!/bin/sh
printf '\n\033[42mCreating cgroup hierarchy\033[m\n\n' &&
for d in /sys/fs/cgroup/*; do
        f=$(basename $d)
        echo "looking at $f"
        if [ "$f" = "cpuset" ]; then
                echo 1 | sudo tee -a $d/cgroup.clone_children;
        elif [ "$f" = "memory" ]; then
                echo 1 | sudo tee -a $d/memory.use_hierarchy;
        fi
        sudo mkdir -p $d/$USER
        sudo chown -R $USER $d/$USER
        # add current process to cgroup
       echo $PPID > $d/$USER/tasks
done

sh workaround.sh
```

give me a "permission denied" on line            `echo $PPID > $d/$USER/tasks`
but works.

```
lxc-start -n mylinux
echo $?
0
```

Now the problem.
I want the containers to start on boot(they are unprivileged) so lxc-autostart
don't work
I have created the file /etc/rc.local, but fail
I have tried this way

```
#!/bin/bash
# Action at boot

start() {
su - lxcunpriv -c "lxc-start -n mylinux"
su - lxcunpriv -c "lxc-start -n myothercontainer"
....
}
```

in this case failed with the error

```
  lxc-start: mylinux: lxccontainer.c: wait_on_daemonized_start: 833 No such file or directory - Failed to receive the container state
    lxc-start: mylinux: tools/lxc_start.c: main: 330 The container failed to start
    lxc-start: mylinux: tools/lxc_start.c: main: 333 To get more details, run the container in foreground mode
    lxc-start: mylinux: tools/lxc_start.c: main: 336 Additional information can be obtained by setting the --logfile and --logpriority options
```

and also this to exec the "workaround" script from rc.local

```
su - lxcunpriv <<EOF
sh workaround.sh
lxc-start -n myothercontainer
EOF
```

in this case the workaround run but the lxc-start command fail with the same error

```
 lxc-start --name mylinux
    lxc-start: mylinux: lxccontainer.c: wait_on_daemonized_start: 833 No such file or directory - Failed to receive the container state...
```

Of course if I do

```
su - lxcunpriv
sh workaround.sh
lxc-start -n mylinux
```

it works, why don't work also from rc-local?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found
I edit rc.local

Instead of those lines

```
su - lxcunpriv <<EOF
sh workaround.sh
lxc-start -n myothercontainer
EOF
```

the correct lines are those

```
start() {
su - lxcunpriv <<EOF
/var/lxcunpriv/workaround.sh
lxc-start --name mycontainer
lxc-start --name myothercontainer
...
EOF    
}
```

The container start.
The problem was the word "sh" before the script, which start another subshell and vanish the effect of the workaround script.